# Apply different functions along one axis of a Tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am looking for the best way, to calculate the spherical bessel functions with an increasing order along one axis of a tensor. My tensor has the shape `(n, x, y)` where `n` denotes the order of the bessel function. For this code I simplified them as `j_n(x) = x**n` but for the real functions, the complexity increases very fast for larger `n`.

I only need to compute the upper triangle of my tensor, so the number of points decreases with larger values of n. This could look like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

test_data = tf.random.normal((40, 40, 100)) 
x = tf.where(np.triu(np.ones((40, 40)))[..., None] , test_data, tf.zeros_like(test_data))
x[:, :, 0]

<tf.Tensor: shape=(40, 40), dtype=float32, numpy=
array([[-1.157, -1.376, -0.427, ...,  0.031,  0.846,  0.813],
       [ 0.   , -2.165,  0.873, ..., -1.044,  0.999,  0.778],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  2.528, ...,  0.409,  0.041, -1.473],
       ...,
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   , ...,  1.587,  1.987, -0.626],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   , ...,  0.   , -1.137, -0.859],
       [ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   , ...,  0.   ,  0.   , -0.901]],
      dtype=float32)>

      x_sparse = tf.sparse.from_dense(x)
```

For now I have two approaches to handle this, both using `tf.map_fn` either on the full tensor which involves a lot of unnecessary computations or on a sparse tensor, which even for large n is slower.

```
def func(inp):
    x, a = inp
    return x**a

def func_sparse(inp):
    x, a = inp
    return tf.sparse.SparseTensor(x.indices, x.values**a, x.dense_shape)

%timeit tf.map_fn(func, (x, tf.range(40, dtype=tf.float32)), fn_output_signature=tf.float32)
# 18.8 ms ± 89.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit tf.map_fn(func_sparse, (x_sparse, tf.range(40, dtype=tf.float32)), fn_output_signature=tf.SparseTensorSpec([None, None], dtype=tf.float32))
# 30.1 ms ± 166 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Is there a better way, to apply a function with increasing order along an axis of a tensor? The `%timeit` above does not consider the generation of the sparse tensor, which makes it even slower. Is there a way to avoid the unnecessary computations and still be faster and more memory efficient?

Comment: A triangle matrix is not really sparse, I doubt you can achieve a good performance increase with a SparseTensor. Your best bet is probably to rewrite your bessel function in a vectorized way to skip the `map_fn`(if you can).

Comment: Consider also using `@tf.function` decorator, I get an 20x speed up in your example.

Comment: I did wrap the `func` inside a `@tf.function` without any changes. I did not expect `tf.map_fn` to profit from it. How would you rewrite a function, that acts on each row seperatly? `tf.unstack` it and iterate over the list of tensors?

Comment: You need to wrap the call to `tf.map_fn`, not `func`. As for rewriting the function, it depends on the function, I don't have any "works-for-all" solution unfortunately.